# After migrating site to another server Magento 2 functionalities not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I migrated site to another server and now functionalists not working like  account creation , email registration , checkout etc . On last server everything is perfect. What is going on here ? Any idea ?

Comment: any console error or deploy static content try

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan  I ran all commads , upgrade , deploy , reindex etc . no error . all css and javascript is perfect just mangento functionalities are missing

Comment: is any php version change or is there any error log on server or even in Magento , plz check

Comment: how to check that changes @SaurabhRanjan ?

Answer (score 1):

There may be any reason but most common issues may be :

1) PHP version issues

Check php version on `old server` as well as `new server`.

> To check the php version

create a new file lets say `phpinfo.php` at root level of both server 
In `phpinfo.php`

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

and execute this file like below

2) Check errors in console.

3) Check log files of your website as well as of your `server`.

> open error.log

```
inrsaurabh@maddyboy:/var/log/apache2$ sudo nano error.log
```

4) Start disabling external extension one by one and check if problem solved.

Comment: I got a clue .Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found   . but I dont know how to access my online bitnami phpmyadmin to run a sql command

Comment: @ephemeral congrats , where you found the this log ?

Comment: @plz share a bit more info about your server sir.

Comment: No it was not in log . my general -> web   setting was not opening. Now few errors fixed due to this . but now still some errors happening . like login and sign up etc I think that are because of  I migrated some tables from magento 1  of customers